# How to detect with bash that the cursor is on the title bar (Wayland)

Tags: wayland, kde5

I am trying to detect whether the mouse cursor is over the title bar of a window or not. I was able to achieve this in X11 using the commands listed in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438129/how-to-detect-with-bash-that-the-cursor-is-on-the-title-bar), but these commands do not work well in Wayland. For example, `xdotool getmouselocation` gives the location in a strange way and always gives the same window ID, except for Google Chrome and other applications like TeamViewer. This means that I cannot get any information about each window or compare the mouse location to the title bar to determine whether it is over the title bar. Do you know of any method that would allow me to achieve this in KDE with Wayland